# Python While loop problem. How do I get my while loop to detect if a person say yes, y, n or no?

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop

I created a while loop that basically takes the user's input and it's suppose to detect when the user didn't type yes, y, no, n, and restart the process. I tried with charArt(0) because I am trying to get it to detect the first letter y or n, incase the user types y or yes or n, no, and it would be able to detect yes or no. But it's giving me an error.

```
   wants_to_play = "x"
        while wants_to_play.charAt(0) != "y" and wants_to_play.charAt(0) != "n":
            wants_to_play = input("Do you want to play? (Yes/No): ").lower()
            if wants_to_play == "y" or wants_to_play == "yes":
                print("Let's play!")
            elif wants_to_play == "n" or wants_to_play == "no":
                print("Aww too bad, maybe next time!")
                exit()
            elif wants_to_play == 'exit':
                break
            else:
                print("There has been error, type yes or no: ")
                print("Or you can type in exit to end the game!")
```

Comment: `charAt(0)` is Javascript; python's equivalent is `wants_to_play[0]`

Comment: [str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Comment: Note that you can use `if wants_to_play in ("y", "yes")` for neatness.

Answer (score 0):

You should use startswith() as suggested in the comments. The other mistake is that you are using "and" when it seems like you want to use "or".

```
while !wants_to_play.startswith("y") or !wants_to_play.startswith("n"):
    ...
```

should do nicely.

Comment: That should be `not` instead of `!`; and the `and` was correct. Changing it to `or` will give a condition that is always true.

Answer (score 0):

everyone seems to have answered it, I would however provide a different solution. I find it a bit odd that you check for the `wants_to_play` to start with "y" in the `while` loop and in the `if` statement. I personally would use recursion in this case:

```
def ask_to_play():
    wants_to_play = input("Do you want to play? (Yes/No): ").lower()
    if wants_to_play.startswith("y"):
        print("Let's play!")
    elif wants_to_play.startswith("n") or wants_to_play == 'exit':
        print("Aww too bad, maybe next time!")
        exit()
    else:
        print("There has been error, type yes or no: ")
        print("Or you can type in exit to end the game!")
        ask_to_play()
ask_to_play()
```

But this works just fine:

```
wants_to_play = "x"
while wants_to_play[0] != "y" and wants_to_play[0] != "n":
    wants_to_play = input("Do you want to play? (Yes/No): ").lower()
    if wants_to_play == "y" or wants_to_play == "yes":
        print("Let's play!")
    elif wants_to_play == "n" or wants_to_play == "no":
        print("Aww too bad, maybe next time!")
        exit()
    elif wants_to_play == 'exit':
        break
    else:
        print("There has been error, type yes or no: ")
        print("Or you can type in exit to end the game!")
```